# Update Statement in oracle PL/SQL updating the values to null

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE FD DCS
  SET DCS.F_DISTANCE =
    (SELECT FD.F_DISTANCE
    FROM TMP FD
    WHERE FD.DATE_SID = DCS.DATE_SID
    AND FD.SID = DCS.SID
    AND FD.DA_SID = DCS.DASID
    AND FD.AA_SID = DCS.AA
    AND FD.F_DISTANCE IS NOT NULL
    )
WHERE DCS.BATCH_ID=BATCH_ID;
```

The inner SQl query is updating all the satisfied values to the FD table's column F_distance but where subquery didn't match it is updating the FD table F_Distance values to null. I don't want to update the values to null.
please suggest what to do.

Comment: Oracle or MySql ?  is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ORACLE you can use NVL

```
UPDATE FD DCS
SET DCS.F_DISTANCE = NVL(
  (SELECT FD.F_DISTANCE
  FROM TMP FD
  WHERE FD.DATE_SID = DCS.DATE_SID
  AND FD.SID = DCS.SID
  AND FD.DA_SID = DCS.DASID
  AND FD.AA_SID = DCS.AA
  AND FD.F_DISTANCE IS NOT NULL
  ), DCS.F_DISTANCE)
WHERE DCS.BATCH_ID=BATCH_ID;
```

In this case if the result is null the NVL return 0 (you cna change with the value you prefer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but DCS.F_DISTANCE column is already having some numeric values rather than 0, i need to save them from getting null.

Comment: If i undertand right if the value is null you want the previous value.. then i have update the answer  .. hope is useful